# Relative Clause/Purpose Clause

Tags: grammar

A. This machine crushes up oranges and removes the seed.

A1 This machine is for oranges to be crushed and the seeds to be removed.

B.    My aim is so that my children are happy.

B1.  My aim is for my children to be happy.

1. Is the second version in (A1.) example a For-infinitival relative Clause, or  rather a purpose clause? How would you call it?
2. Is «so that my children are happy» a content clause, it seems to me it has a noun function.
3. What grammar phenomenon does the second version in (b1.) contain? Is it also RC or something different?

Deeply grateful for any help!

Comment: (We call the seeds of oranges _pips_.) A1 doesn't work with the passive voice. You need to say 'This machine is to crush oranges...' B is incorrect too - we can't use _so that_ after _aim_.

Comment: Kate, thank you very much forn your reply. Is there a particular rule explaining why the A1 is incorrect, or as a native speaker, ypu know, it doesn.t have any sense. Thanks!

Comment: Because you used the passive! We say  _a machine to crush oranges_ or _for crushing oranges_, not _for oranges to be crushed_.

Comment: @KateBunting - I find *pips* to be distinctly British - as an AmE speaker, I'd always call them *seeds*.  Google ngram seems to agree - "orange seeds" is more popular than "orange pips" in the American English corpus; the reverse is true in British English.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - You learn something new every day!

Comment: Kate, i  am sorry for being enquisitive, but does it mean that  For-Infinitival RC doesn't allow passive to be used in Subordinate Clause.

Comment: i.e These are climate changing efforts for forest fires to be kept that low.  
            Here are the instructions to be followed. - are both wrong and should be repalced with "to keep" and "to folow". ?